# Generate all real combinations in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to generate all combinations (not permutations) in VB .NET, I've been search and all I found is for permutations (some says combinations but when I was try it, all are permutations).

What I need is to generate combinations from string array:

```
Dim data_array As String() = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"}
```

I need that:

If I say just 1 length, it must returns:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

If I say 2 length, it must returs:

```
oneone
onetwo
onethree
onefour
... etc ...
twoone
twotwo
twothree
... etc ...
```

And continues til end with all combinations.

If I say more length do it as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you want to generate all combinations but it looks to me like to are trying to generate  all permutations.

You might try to do it recursively if you wish.  If you just want to generate combinations then test the Root parameter to see if it contains myStr before appending it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim data_array As String() = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"}
    Dim buffer As New List(Of String)

Public Sub Permute(ByVal Root As String, ByVal Depth As Integer, ByVal Buffer As List(Of String))

    For Each myStr As String In data_array

            If Depth <= 1 Then
                Buffer.Add(Root + myStr)
            Else
                Permute(Root + myStr, Depth - 1, Buffer)
            End If

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Permute("", 2, buffer)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to inspect the contents of the Buffer variable.  It contains a list of the strings.  I've called it with a depth of 2, which means that you should get oneone, onetwo, onethree etc.  Call it with a depth of 3 and you'll get oneoneone, oneonetwo, oneonethree, onetwoone etc.

Comment: Hi, it crashes when I add too many options in array (for privacy I cannot post here the full array) and numbers to generate: System.OutOfMemoryException, is there any way to fix it? (split array in parts and take part by part, any idea?), thanks in advanced.

Comment: How big is the source array you are trying to permute?

Comment: The array contains 100 strings and I've tried to permute with 3 depth, and it crushed.

Comment: I can't see a list of a million strings giving a modern computer many problems. And since the recursion should only go down to three function calls then stack space shouldn't be a problem either. Instead of passing in a List object and adding to it, how about passing in a file handle of some kind and writing the strings out to that?

Comment: If it's *combinations* that you're after (and not permutations) then you could save space by using the Depth parameter to limit the strings that you iterate over.  For instance, you'd start by iterating over 100 strings, then on the next recursion you'd iterate over the remaining 99 strings, and the next would be the remaining 98.  You'd need to pass in an additional parameter which was a list or array of all the indexes that you were currently using for building up the string.

Answer (score 2):

This should returns all combinations of said depth in a `IEnumerable(Of String)`

```
 Function GetCombinations(ByVal depth As Integer, ByVal values As String()) As IEnumerable(Of String)
        If depth > values.Count + 1 Then Return New List(Of String)
        Dim result = New List(Of String)

        For i = 0 To depth - 1
            For y = 0 To values.Count - 1
                If i = 0 Then
                    result.Add(values(y))
                Else
                    result.Add(values(i - 1) + values(y))
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
```

Edit:

Example usage:

```
        Dim data_array As String() = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}
        Dim reslt = GetCombinations(2, data_array)
```

Comment: whe I use it (for get clear results with that array: {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"} ) it returns: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 1 1 1 1 1, with the other array only returns the first character of each string as the other result, repeating the first...

Comment: What are your exact arguments of the function? Using your {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"} with a depth of 2 returns 1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16 as expected.

Comment: As I said I used it for get clear results, whe I use other array, the function returns only the first character of each string in the array: o t t f f s o o o o o o, for that reason I used numbers (as strings quoted by "") for get a clear result...

Comment: It is still unclear to me what the problem is. Best is to edit your question with EXACTLY what you are doing. (Code example)

Comment: I'm using your code, Dim data_array As String() = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"} / Dim reslt = GetCombinations(2, data_array) and for get any part as separately I use: For Each item In reslt / TextBox1.AppendText(item(0) & Environment.NewLine) / Next  and it returns that I said in previous comment  (/ = 'line-break')

Comment: Why would you use item(0)? It only displays the first character of each item in your results. If you want the whole text, use item.

Comment: It works but not combine all, it stops at 16, it should continious with 21 22 23 24 25 26 31 32 33 ... etc, til end with 66 if I use 3 of depth it returns 1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16,21,22,23,24,25,26, and it stops here... is there any way to continious?