# Creating a Fixture List for a set number of Weeks

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, fixtures

I have seen some examples on forums but they don't seem to cater for what I need.

I am looking at creating a randomly generated fixture list for a football league.

I have 38 gameweeks, and anywhere between 2 and 20 teams in a league (all even numbers). What I need is the logic as to how to create the list.

I want to create a  list which will look like the following:

```
Gameweek 1

A v B
C v D
E v F


Gamweeek 2

A v C
D v E
F v B
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can go about creating this?

Comment: So 38 is a constant, when you have so few teams, how do you find fixturs for the other weeks?

Comment: Say there are only 2 teams the fixtures would look like

Gameweek 1

A v B

Gameweek 2

B v A

Gameweek 3

A  v B etc.

Comment: I basically want to create 38 gameweeks, where every team plays each other home and away. If there are only 2 teams, then to fill the 38 gameweeks, the 2 teams will have to play each other 19 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a math problem!  Specifically, permutations (with some recursion).  Here are some examples I found with a quick google search:

http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/algorithms/article.php/c5607/Permutations-in-Visual-Basic--Generating-All-Possible-Combinations.htm

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_2005_permute.html

[Generate all real combinations in VB .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976215/generate-all-real-combinations-in-vb-net)

This examples should get you started.  The last one seems more practical to what you want to do.  If you get stuck along the way, post back.

Comment: C# and VB.Net all compile down to the same common language.  As such, converting between C# and VB is not difficult and can be automated here (http://converter.telerik.com/).  Don't allow the syntax to throw you off.  Just because you know (or are learning) C# does not mean a VB.net response can not shed light on your issue.  With all programming languages, it's never the syntax that should be the stumbling block but the logic you need to solve the problem.  What you should be focused on is how the developers use recursion to create permutations.